# Running Python in R Studio

Tags: python, rstudio, miniconda, reticulate

I'm trying to start using R studio as IDE for python, but I cannot even start doing so because miniconda installation fails to complete. As follows.

```
reticulate::repl_python()
No non-system installation of Python could be found.
Would you like to download and install Miniconda?
Miniconda is an open source environment management system for Python.
See https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html for more details.

Would you like to install Miniconda? [Y/n]: import pandas as pd 
Please answer yes or no: 
* Installing Miniconda -- please wait a moment ...
* Downloading "https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe" ...
trying URL 'https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 55508040 bytes (52.9 MB)
downloaded 52.9 MB

Error: miniconda installation failed [exit code 2]
```

Comment: Did you solve the error?